# Multiple yaml file configuration in spring cloud function definition

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

we have around 20 different spring cloud function definition and kafka bindings . its very difficult to maintain it in a single yaml file.

Hence logically grouped into 10 different yaml files for better management.

Had tried configuring 10 yaml files using spring.config.location or spring.config.name in a comma-separated list.
Only last yaml file is getting loaded .

Had tried loading all the yaml files using YamlPropertySourceLoader and add it to applicationContext environment.

Both the approches didnt work .
spring boot : 3.0.4